# How to get and analyze Chrome Network Details bug reports properly

Tags: macos, google-chrome, permissions

I'm facing strange symptom I can not browse Internet using Chrome but other browser such Chromium works. This problem occurred several times. So, I would like to analyze this problem as much as possible. Could you kindly advice me how to do it?

**Verification**:

- OK: Check other browser
- OK: Norton Application block setting all
  Google Chrome is allow

But, I got an error from Norton Internet Security about Google Chrome is not allowed. It's very strange things happen on my Mac recently. Once it's allowed it worked once. But, It happened again soon.

I refer Chromium site to analyze my Chrome issue. But, I'm not sure how to run the command and identify the log. I got below log after run the command but it seems be something wrong. Could you tell me about it?

**Environment:**

OSX 10.9.2

Chrome verion 33.0.1750.149

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/for-testers/providing-network-details

**Command on terminal:**

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --foo --bar=2
```

**Terminal:**

```
Google:~ apple$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --foo --bar=2

2014-03-12 18:28:43.054 Google Chrome Helper[6754:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x5f2f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-03-12 18:28:43.549 Google Chrome Helper[6756:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6327, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-03-12 18:28:46.950 Google Chrome Helper[6754:507] CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server

2014-03-12 18:28:46.950 Google Chrome Helper[6754:507] CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server

2014-03-12 18:28:52.253 Google Chrome Helper[6758:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6223, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-03-12 18:28:52.306 Google Chrome Helper[6759:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x5e2f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-03-12 18:28:52.590 Google Chrome Helper[6758:507] CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server

2014-03-12 18:28:52.591 Google Chrome Helper[6758:507] CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server

2014-03-12 18:31:44.464 Google Chrome Helper[6770:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6327, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

[image]

I really need this Mac for my Android development, so I don't install ex-application to get malware type of things.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that *CFMessagePort error 1100 (0x44c)* occur when a process tries to open a named message port under a name which another process already has open. I think the *Permission denied* part is sloppy wording by macOS. If you've only got one instance of Chrome or Chromium running, it's a bug in Chrom(-e/-ium).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the response delay. I still investigating about this.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the above message - this should not be your issue:

> CFMessagePort error 1100 (0x44c)

I ran Chrome in `lldb` and the following was included in the output:

> 2014-03-25 02:16:50.453 Google Chrome Helper[5183:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6327, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
>   See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

Referring to the file stated (`/usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h`), it notes that the command `bootstrap_register()` has been used since 10.0 but has been deprecated as of 10.5.

Thus, the error is thrown as you are running Mavericks. Although this is not a fatal error as my Chrome connects just fine, if a bit CPU and memory hungry.